# Is there a way to know what options and properties are available to use when querying for calendar events with the Graph API?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

This may be a dumb question, but I'm kind of stuck when trying to figure out what options I have available when querying for calendar events using Microsoft's Java Graph API.

In their tutorial they have the following code example.

```
public static List<Event> getEvents(String accessToken) {
    ensureGraphClient(accessToken);

    // Use QueryOption to specify the $orderby query parameter
    final List<Option> options = new LinkedList<Option>();
    // Sort results by createdDateTime, get newest first
    options.add(new QueryOption("orderby", "createdDateTime DESC"));

    // GET /me/events
    IEventCollectionPage eventPage = graphClient
        .me()
        .events()
        .buildRequest(options)
        .select("subject,organizer,start,end")
        .get();

    return eventPage.getCurrentPage();
}
```

They are using the orderby option and telling it to use createdDateTime DESC ordering. Is there a list of other options and their possible values somewhere? For example, what option would I use if I only wanted events from 2020-10-01 to 2020-10-31?

My second question is regarding the properties that they're selecting (subject, organizer, start, end). Is there also a list of possible properties that can be selected for each event?

Comment: You can see all the properties in the [event resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). You can see the ODATA query options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#odata-system-query-options). You can use filter query parameter that can filter the data. But remember that some properties/endpoints support them and some may not.

Comment: Thank you Shiva, that's exactly what I was looking for. I tried searching through the docs, but it got a bit overwhelming and I wasn't having any luck.

Comment: Glad to here that gottfred :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the properties in the [event resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). You can see the ODATA query options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#odata-system-query-options). You can use filter query parameter that can filter the data. But remember that some properties/endpoints support them and some may not.